# Constant changing password

Tags: domain, password-management, password-generation

Anyway of making a domain account password change (say every 5 minutes) automatically.

Linking to a web app or mobile app would be awesome

Thanks

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586). You are asking us how to implement a vaguely described solution to an unspecified problem. That won't work. **You have to tell us what the problem you are trying to solve is**, you can't start the description with your solution.

Comment: I need a program which will automatically change a domain users password, so the user would need to login with the most recent password. Large companies sometimes use tags which provide a new password every 20 seconds or so. So looking for a similar method. wanting to implement for one user before rolling it out across the domain.

Comment: Ahh, now it makes sense. You *did* ask the wrong question. Those things don't work by changing the password on the app end! (If they did, clock skew between the tag and the server would cause logins to fail. You *can't* implement that kind of scheme by changing the password on the server side.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work.

Schemes that change the password frequently require accounting for clock slippage between the user (or his device) and the server. Otherwise, if it's close to a time boundary (and, in many cases, not that close), a user will often get the wrong password.

Also, policies typically need to be enforced. For example, if a password is "used up", generally it is a policy requirement that it not be used again. The user would have to wait for the next password. And, in some cases, you will need to make the user wait for the next password anyway because the slippage is too great.

Schemes such as you describe are implemented by hooking the server's password checking process and intelligently comparing it to the possible passwords the user might send. Changing the password frequently on the server side will not work.